# Proving $\sum\limits_{m=1}^\infty\dfrac{x^2}{m^2-x^2} = \dfrac{1}{2}- \dfrac{\pi x\cot(\pi x)}{2}$

Tags: complex-analysis

How can we prove

$$\sum_{m=1}^\infty\dfrac{x^2}{m^2-x^2} = \dfrac{1}{2} - \dfrac{\pi x\cot(\pi x)}{2}$$

using complex analysis or Fourier series or Integrals? I have proved it using elementary techniques like splitting and sum, telescoping by grouping the terms and stuff, however I'm most interested in an approach making use of complex analysis or Fourier series or Integrals, however any approach (given that it isn't too elementary) is most welcomed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried contour integration?

Comment: Yeah but I'm not reaching anywhere using it

Comment: @MarkViola Do you have a solution using contour integration?

Comment: Yes.  See my posted solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(z)=\frac{\cot(\pi z)}{z^2-x^2}$ and $C$ be the contour $|z|=N+1/2$.  Then, we have

$$\lim_{N\to \infty }\oint_{|z|=N+1/2} \frac{\cot(\pi z)}{z^2-x^2}\,dz=0$$

In addition, we have from the residue theorem,

$$\oint_{|z|=N+1/2} \frac{\cot(\pi z)}{z^2-x^2}\,dz=2\pi i \left(\frac{\cot(\pi x)}{x}+\sum_{n=-N}^N \frac{1}{\pi(n^2-x^2)}\right)$$

Letting $N\to \infty$ reveals

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{(n^2-x^2)}=-\frac{\pi \cot(\pi x)}{x}$$

and hence

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^2}{(n^2-x^2)}=\frac12-\frac{\pi x\cot(\pi x)}{2}$$

Comment: Using that $\cot(x)/x$ is even is indeed a good trick.

Comment: How did the $\pi$ came in the denominator?

Comment: The $\pi$ in the denominator comes from differentiating $\sin(\pi z)$.

Comment: @reuns Thank you my friend!  I hope that you're doing well and staying safe and healthy.

Comment: It should be $\dfrac{1}{2} - \dfrac{\pi x\cot(\pi x)}{2}$

Comment: Yes.  I've corrected the typos.

Comment: @MarkViola There's one more typo in your proof

Comment: What is the typo?

Comment: @MarkViola It's already perfect :)

Answer (score 1):

*Probably too elementary*
$$\frac{x^2}{m^2-x^2}=\frac x 2 \left(\frac 1{m-x}-\frac 1{m+x} \right)$$
$$S_1=\sum_{m=1}^p \frac 1{m-x}=\psi (p-x+1)-\psi (1-x)=H_{p-x}-H_{-x}$$
$$S_2=\sum_{m=1}^p \frac 1{m+x}=\psi(p+x+1)-\psi (x+1)=H_{p+x}-H_x$$ Now, using the asymptotics of the digamma function or the asymptotics of the generalized harmonic numbers
$$\frac x 2(S_1-S_2)=\frac{1-\pi  x \cot (\pi  x)}{2} -\frac{x^2}{p}+\frac{x^2}{2 p^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^3}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)=\sum_{m=1}^\infty\dfrac{x}{m^2-x^2} - \dfrac{1}{
2x} + \dfrac{\pi \cot(\pi x)}{2}$ is a $1$-periodic entire function.

$g(x)=f(x)/x$ is entire and bounded on $\Re(x)\in [0,1]$ thus everywhere.

Whence $g(x)=g(i\infty)=0$.

Comment: Can you repeat?

Comment: @reunds Could you please elaborate more in your proof?

Comment: Elaborate on what?

Comment: shouldn't it be $xf(x)$?

Comment: Bounded entire functions are constant (Liouville theorem). So $g(x)=C$ and $g(i\infty)=0$ gives $C=0$. @BooleanWick